# Text Information not scrape properly-Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to scrape the text information between the following HTML. My code below is not working properly for cases where tag and class names are same. Here i need to get the text in single list element and not as two different list element. The code i have written here for the case where there is no split like below. In my case i need to scrape both kind of text and append it to a single list.

**Sample HTML code(where list element is one)- working correctly:**

```
<DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">The board of Hillshire Brands has withdrawn its recommendation to acquire frozen foods maker Pinnacle Foods, clearing the way for Tyson Foods' $8.55bn takeover bid.</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Last Monday Tyson won the bidding war for Hillshire, maker of Ball Park hot dogs, with a $63-a-share offer, topping rival poultry processor Pilgrim's Pride's $7.7bn bid.</SPAN></P>
```

**Sample HTML Code(where list element is two):**

```
<DIV CLASS="c5"><BR><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">HIGHLIGHT:</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;News analysis<BR></SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">M&amp;A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space, writes Neil Munhsi</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Pickles may go with sandwiches, as Hillshire Brands chief executive Sean Connolly put it two weeks ago.</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">But many were puzzled by the US food group's announcement that it would pay $6.6bn to acquire New Jersey-based rival Pinnacle Foods, maker of Vlasic pickles and Birds Eye frozen food.</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Without the sort of mooted cost savings necessary to justify the purchase price, many saw the move by Hillshire, known in the US for Ball Park hot dogs and Jimmy Dean sausages, as a way to head off a potential takeover.</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P>
```

**Python Code:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
tree = html.fromstring(response)
values = [[''.join(text for text in div.xpath('.//p[@class="c9"]//span[@class="c2"]//text()'))] for div in tree.xpath('//div[@class="c5"]') if div.getchildren()]
        split_at = ','
textvalues = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(values, lambda x: x != split_at) if k]
list2 = [x for x in textvalues[0] if x]
def purify(list2):
     for (i, sl) in enumerate(list2):
          if type(sl) == list:
              list2[i] = purify(sl)
            return [i for i in list2 if i != [] and i != '']
list3=purify(list2)
flattened = [val for sublist in list3 for val in sublist]
```

**Current Output:**

```
["M&A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space, writes Neil Munhsi","--Remaining text--"]
```

**Expected Sample Output:**

```
["M&A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space, writes Neil Munhsi --Remaining text--"]
```

Please help me to resolve the above issue.

Comment: You can just do this to get the expected output -```flattened = [' '.join(map(str,flattened))]```

Comment: I need to append the two list element alone. But actually i have other final list elements which also got appended and giving me wrong results.

Comment: I didn't get you, can you post the errors you are getting.

Comment: I need to append the two list element alone. But actually i have other final list elements which also got appended and giving me wrong results. The result is coming as ['1 of 80 DOCUMENTS','<List element text>']. All the list element got appended as single element. say for all 80 documents element text is coming as single line text.

Comment: Did you remove the existing statement - ```flattened = [val for sublist in list3 for val in sublist]``` and tried the above code? I meant to add it after that.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur , I don't get why you map flattened, since it's already strings inside. Could you explain ?

Comment: No. I didnt remove. The issue is it is appending properly for that particular element and not for all element. Say for example[['1 of 80 DOCUMENTS',<Listelement1>],['2 of 80 DOCUMENTS',<Listelement2>]] etc.. Because of changing my code for list element as you said before, now i am getting only 1 of 80 DOCUMENTS and all list elements in single text.

Comment: @T.Nel Just to make sure if there are other types in the list, an error is not raised. If it guaranteed that only `str` type element are present then mapping is unnecessary.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur - Could you please guide me a solution

Comment: @Mho I'm not able to understand your problem. Post your complete code and tell me what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to extract the single HTML page text that contains Title, City,Industry, Text information etc., for many documents. Say for eg. [['1 of 80 DOCUMENTS','City1',<TextBody1>],['2 of 80 DOCUMENTS','City2', <Text body2>]]  into separate list and import each list as rows into MYSQL DB. The problem here is, for some text body the tags are different as shared above causing text split for SQL single row text into two rows.Board has yet to back higher offer
Tyson Foods has knocked out rival poultry producer Pilgrim's Pride in the bidding war for Hillshire Brands with what it called a "binding"

Comment: In the above comment. Board has yet to back higher offer.Tyson Foods has knocked out rival poultry producer Pilgrim's Pride in the bidding war for Hillshire Brands with what it called a "binding". These two text are coming as two different rows though they both should come in single row. For some document in the HTML, Highlight text and separated by one blank line will not come.

Comment: <DIV CLASS="c5"><BR><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">HIGHLIGHT:</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;News analysis<BR></SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">M&A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Pickles may go with sandwiches, as Hillshire Brands.</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">But many were puzzled </SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Without the sort of mooted cost savings necessary to justify the purchase price</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P>

Comment: As i am extracting text based on div-c5,p-c9 and span-c2 class, the text "M&A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space" and "Pickles may go with sandwiches, as Hillshire Brands" get split into two different rows where it should come as single row causing issue. For some HTML page where the Highlight text  is not there, i am getting correct result.

Comment: Let  me know if you are able to understand my issue properly.

Comment: BS do not support xpath, I think you are using lxml

Comment: The code above is exactly what i am using to do my work.

Comment: yes i have imported "from lxml import html"

Comment: Can someone help me on the above issue?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a="""
<DIV CLASS="c5"><BR><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">HIGHLIGHT:</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;News analysis<BR></SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">M&amp;A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space, writes Neil Munhsi</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Pickles may go with sandwiches, as Hillshire Brands chief executive Sean Connolly put it two weeks ago.</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">But many were puzzled by the US food group's announcement that it would pay $6.6bn to acquire New Jersey-based rival Pinnacle Foods, maker of Vlasic pickles and Birds Eye frozen food.</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Without the sort of mooted cost savings necessary to justify the purchase price, many saw the move by Hillshire, known in the US for Ball Park hot dogs and Jimmy Dean sausages, as a way to head off a potential takeover.</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P>
"""
l = BeautifulSoup(a).text.split('\n')
b = [' '.join(l[1:])]
print b
```

Output:

```
[u"M&A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space, writes Neil Munhsi  Pickles may go with sandwiches, as Hillshire Brands chief executive Sean Connolly put it two weeks ago. But many were puzzled by the US food group's announcement that it would pay $6.6bn to acquire New Jersey-based rival Pinnacle Foods, maker of Vlasic pickles and Birds Eye frozen food. Without the sort of mooted cost savings necessary to justify the purchase price, many saw the move by Hillshire, known in the US for Ball Park hot dogs and Jimmy Dean sausages, as a way to head off a potential takeover.\xa0 "]
```

Comment: Here i cannot split the text based on new line as i need to scrape so many columns where each column is separated by '\n' character.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '''<DIV CLASS="c5"><BR><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">HIGHLIGHT:</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;News analysis<BR></SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">M&amp;A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space, writes Neil Munhsi</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Pickles may go with sandwiches, as Hillshire Brands chief executive Sean Connolly put it two weeks ago.</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">But many were puzzled by the US food group's announcement that it would pay $6.6bn to acquire New Jersey-based rival Pinnacle Foods, maker of Vlasic pickles and Birds Eye frozen food.</SPAN></P>
<P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Without the sort of mooted cost savings necessary to justify the purchase price, many saw the move by Hillshire, known in the US for Ball Park hot dogs and Jimmy Dean sausages, as a way to head off a potential takeover.</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P>'''

html = etree.HTML(text)

res = html.xpath('//span[@class="c2" and ../@class="c9"]/text()')

print([''.join(res)])
```

out:

```
 ["M&A simmers as producers swallow up brands to win shelf space, writes Neil MunhsiPickles may go with sandwiches, as Hillshire Brands chief executive Sean Connolly put it two weeks ago.But many were puzzled by the US food group's announcement that it would pay $6.6bn to acquire New Jersey-based rival Pinnacle Foods, maker of Vlasic pickles and Birds Eye frozen food.Without the sort of mooted cost savings necessary to justify the purchase price, many saw the move by Hillshire, known in the US for Ball Park hot dogs and Jimmy Dean sausages, as a way to head off a potential takeover.\xa0"]
```

Comment: It is still giving as one single row and not as multiple rows.